# Opencart 1.5.6 error | Notice: Undefined index: option_value

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

Some of my *product pages* keep showing me this **message**:

> “Notice: Undefined index: option_value in
>   /home/paper/osconvites/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php
>   on line 411Notice: Undefined index: option_value in
>   /home/paper/osconvites/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php
>   on line 411Notice: Undefined index: option_value in
>   /home/paper/osconvites/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php
>   on line 411”

Comment: Make sure vqcache has 777 permission

Comment: Can you post the code of your vQmod cache file here ?

Comment: I did that @Jack, but nothing changed it still show's the error message.

Comment: Here @NipunTyagi this is the code from the file listed in the error message.

http://jsfiddle.net/brip/49vovtrk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in line no 406

```
if (!isset($product_option['option_value']) || $product_option['option_value'] == '' ) {
    $product_option['option_value'] = '';
}
```